# Use Shortcode on Custom Page

Tags: shortcode, ajax, plugin-contact-form-7

How can I use a shortcode on a custom page in a theme? Let say I have a page that has a jQuery ajax function. I am able to send the data via JQuery post on the `my_form.php` page. On the `confirm.php` page, I want to use a shortcode from Contact Form DB plugin. Below is the source code that I wrote,

**my_form.php**

```
<?php
get_header(); 
// Include all the theme functions    
?>

<form name="season-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label for="carNo" id="label-cust"> Vehicle Registration No</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vehicle_no" id="vehicle_no" placeholder="BHK1991">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label for="email" id="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="myMail@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_payment">Make Payment</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**my_function.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#submit_payment').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var str = $("form[name=season-form]").serialize();
        //alert(str);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url_to_confitm.php,
            data: str 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**confirm.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['vehicle_no'])){
    $vehicle_no = $_POST['vehicle_no'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    echo "Your Data: <br>$vehicle_no <br>$email<p />";
}

echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-table form="season parking form_copy"]');
```

1. I am able to get the result of post data but the shortcode appears to return nothing.
2. If I use the shortcode on `my_form.php` page, it display the data perfectly.

Comment: You can't load php files directly, there is no WordPress environment in that context. You need to use WordPress Ajax hooks. There are many examples on this site if you search around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should this way to handle ajax request. It's the **recommended way to make a ajax call in WordPress.**

**my_function.js**
Update your `jquery` with this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#submit_payment').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var str = $("form[name=season-form]").serialize();
        //alert(str);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '//www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: str + '&action=confirmRequest' 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**ajax_request_handling**
Paste this in `functions.php` of your theme.

```
function _myConfirmHandler()
{
    if(isset($_POST['vehicle_no']))
    {
        $vehicle_no = $_POST['vehicle_no'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        echo "Your Data: <br>$vehicle_no <br>$email<p />";

    }
    echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-table form="season parking form_copy"]');
    echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="23" title="Contact form 1"]');
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_confirmRequest', '_myConfirmHandler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_confirmRequest', '_myConfirmHandler');
```

**For more information refer to the [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).**

Comment: I am still new in Wordpress development. On `my_function.js`, regarding the _url_, do I have to send to admin-ajax.php as well because the page that I want it to display is `confirm.php`.

Comment: Yes you have to send it to `admin-ajax.php`

Comment: @Amran Happy Coding :)

Comment: 1 last thing, how do I want to insert contact form 7 on `functions.php`? I put `echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="6871" title="season parking form_copy"]'); ` after `echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-table form="season parking form_copy"]');` but it just echo the text.

Comment: Are you sure, you wrote it in between the `php` tag .

Comment: Yap, I wrote it in the php tag.  Does contact form 7 plugin support ajax?

Comment: @Amran Please check the updated code. Shortcode is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the update answer @AmitChauhan . I did not understand why I am getting the text. It does not display the form

Comment: Recheck the shortcode